# Is there any metal having the properties of rubber?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, friction

I have seen tires of vehicles to be made of rubber with air filled tube inside.Why can't we have whole tire to be made of rubber?

I hope there would be some use of the air filled tube.Then What is the importance of air filled tube?

---

As known rubber can get charge due to **friction**,that would be hazardous.So,**is there any metal having the properties(greater coefficient of friction,high elasticity) of rubber?** so that charge produced due to friction would get discharged to the earth.Really it would be help full if any one can suggest such an metal.
[image]

Comment: You're asking at least two very different questions, so I would suggest splitting them up, so that each can be addressed appropriately.

Comment: I would think that an air filled tube would be lighter than a completely rubber tire. This would mean that it takes less force to get it to rotate => more efficient cars.

Comment: Solid tires DO exist (but they are usually used in special vehicles).

Comment: And please edit the title. The current one guarantees you downvotes.

Comment: I recently visited Montreal where I got to see their rubber-wheeled Metro trains. The wikipedia page discusses some of the pros and cons of rubber vs. metal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-tyred_metro

Comment: First and second sub-question (v3) is a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41816/2451

Comment: Probably the easiest way to get what you want (avoiding static charge) is to make the tire out of a mildly conductive rubber. Of course in any case (metal or rubber tire) the road also needs to be conductive.

Answer (score 6):

The elasticity of a thin-walled, air-filled tire is much greater than a tire made of solid rubber. This helps the tire absorb more imperfections on the road, and lessens the shock that is transferred to the chassis, as well as the passengers.  An air-filled tire is also lighter than a solid tire, and uses less rubber, making it less expensive.

One of the reasons that tires are made of rubber instead of **metal** is precisely because there's a desirably high friction coefficient between the rubber and the road, which prevents the vehicle from skidding off a curve, and ensures proper braking and acceleration.

The risk of a static discharge due to the rubber tires is relatively minor.  At the fuel pump, you can eliminate the risk of igniting the fuel vapors by placing one hand on the body of your car while grabbing the pump nozzle with the other hand, thereby "grounding" the car before dispensing fuel.

Comment: It's important to note, on the other hand, that the same elasticity of air-filled tires is also a big source of drag and dissipation of energy, essentially by heating the tires in slightly hysteretic compression cycles. This is easily noticeable on a bicycle: flat tires will slow you down, as you spend more energy bending the tire walls.

Comment: @Dmitry Brant.You didn't answer my last question.